# Duplication of stored data

Tags: oracle, string

We  have  oracle  8i   for border  checkpost  automation  where  truck  entry  details  are  stored . Many a  time the  truck data  entered  once  get  duplicated  several time.
 How  to   filter out  such  duplicated  data. As  a part of  this data-storage  becomes  huge. Please  advise  how  to  overcome  this  problem

Comment: Give table structures (with column names) and specify which are the 'key' fields and what criteria to use when determining which of the duplicates to keep/delete.

Answer (score 1):

The standard method is to use a UNIQUE constraint.

Answer (score 0):

This depends upon the discreetness of truck data. If these are same `trucks` that go `in/out` every day then instead of storing new entry for each truck you can Create a new `Truck Detail` table and Put a `Foreign key` in `CheckPost` entry `Table` and just enter new entry every time it passes with `Entry details`.

But if every day new `trucks` go `in/out` then creating New `Truck Detail` table won't be that much feasible and your existing `Schema` is optimum for this situation.

For Performance issues you should look in table [Partitioning](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/partconc.htm).